# Como instanciar objetos en el inicio de una aplicacion web MVC .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web

Tengo una aplicacion web MVC .Net con entityFramework. Lo que necesito es instanciar objetos al momento de iniciar la aplicacion. Como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

En el archivo global.asax puedes inicializar los objetos que desees, en el método app_start

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, pero sería mucho mejor si pudieras complementar tu respuesta con código de ejemplo. Saludos

Comment: Hola omelgarejo, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Sería ideal que añadieras un ejemplo de cómo se haría lo que comentas. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: Hola Álvaro, si fue una de mis primeras respuestas, ya lo tendré en cuenta para una próxima

Comment: @omelgarejo No dejes para la próxima respuesta lo que puedes arreglar en ésta misma. Por favor, edita la respuesta para añadir algo más de información y algún ejemplo de cómo sería lo que comentas. Lee [answer]  para más información.